# Normal approximation to difference of Binomials

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, analysis, statistics

For $N\rightarrow \infty$ I would like an approximation for
$$
{{n}\choose{n/2-p}} - {{n}\choose{n/2-p-1}}
$$
in particular around the point $p\approx n/4$.

It looks like the difference between two gaussians 
$$
\frac{2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{4 p (p+1)+2}{n}} \left(e^{\frac{2 (p+1)^2}{n}}-e^{\frac{2 p^2}{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{n}}
$$
is not working really well. In particular, the accuracy does not seems to increase with $N$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{k-1} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} - \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!} \\
= \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}\right)\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \\
= \frac{n-2k+1}{k(n-k+1)} \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$

If you want to continue to try Gaussian approximation, you can rewrite this as $$\frac{n(n-2k+1)}{k(n-k+1)} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Alternatively you can use Stirling's approximation to as many terms as you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Could you please specify how to perform the Stirling's approximation?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the first result given by your favourite search engine does not suffice.